# Multiple client id prefixes in Mosquitto Broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, messagebroker

Is it possible to configure more than one clientid prefix in mosquitto.conf?

The property name is in plural form "clientid_prefixes" but it doesn't work if I use spaces, comma or semicolon as separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source [code](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/ae309b331cf79663d6a0f2df9a976c6511c552fa/src/handle_connect.c#L275) for the test for this feature it looks like it can only be a single value.

```
/* clientid_prefixes check */
if(db->config->clientid_prefixes){
    if(strncmp(db->config->clientid_prefixes, client_id, strlen(db->config->clientid_prefixes))){
        send__connack(context, 0, CONNACK_REFUSED_NOT_AUTHORIZED);
        rc = 1;
        goto handle_connect_error;
    }
}
```